# How to remove mirrored datasets from MS Access DB?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am experiencing a problem with mirrored datasets. This situation occured because the data model was switched a few months past and I just got recently assigned to this project, which already had a new application and data model done.

I was tasked with importing all the data from the old MS Access application to the new one and here's where the error has its source. The old data model was written in a way that every dataset was also stored as its mirrored counterpart. Imagine a database table like this:

pk | A | B

1 | hello | world

2 | world | hello

I imported the data via a self made staging process via Excel and VBA coding and that worked fine. The staging was necessary because I wanted to create insert statements and therefore had to map all the old IDs, names, ... to the news ones.

While testing the application after the import was done, I realized that the GUI showed all datasets twice. (The reason for it being shown twice and not once and then once again in mirrored form, is the way we fill the ListBox that shows the results)

I found the reason for that error in the mirrored data and now would like to get rid of it. The first idea I had is rather long and probably over-complicated, that's why I am posting here, in hope of finding a shorter solution.

So, my idea is as follows and would use solely VBA coding:

1. Filling recordSet with a SELECT * FROM mirroredDataTable
2. Write a SQL-Statement and check if the recordCount of that statements result is >1 for each record in the recordSet from 1.)
3. If the resultCount is >1 then one of the IDs in that result is written into a new recordSet or Array
4. The recordSet / array from 4.) is parsed again and for each ID in there I create a DELETE statement
5. ???
6. profit

Now I already have an idea for the SQL statement in 2.), but before I begin I'd just like to ensure that there is no "easy" way that I haven't considered yet or just have overlooked.

Would greatly appreciate any help/info/tips you can provide.

PS: It is NOT an option to redesign the whole data model or something among the lines of this (not my decision)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to INTERSECT in MS Access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347535/how-to-intersect-in-ms-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Gord Thompson I was able to solve this issue on a purely SQL basis. See the answer of this subthread for the detailed solution: [How to INTERSECT in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347535/how-to-intersect-in-ms-access)