# How to INTERSECT in MS Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Somehow MS Access doesn't seem to have access to the keyword INTERSECT, which I need right now in order to fix some data errors in my database.

I had a look on older questions and found some answers that tried to solve this problem by using a select distinct [...] inner join [...] construction.

However, this doesn't seem to help me, as the syntax doesn't apply to the table I need to intersect.

Here's a short explanation on what I want to achieve with the INTERSECT:

My table looks like this (simplified):

A | B

hello | world

world | hello

Now these datasets are redundant, but unfortunately can't be caught by a constraint, as they are not exactly the same, but mirrored. That's why they got inserted in the first place...

I think normally I would be able to select all the affected data sets by using a

```
 SELECT A,B FROM tbl
 INTERSECT
 SELECT B,A from tbl
```

After having selected them I could just delete them and would be rid of that problem... Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this using MS Access?

Comment: There is another SO thread [Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337158/how-can-i-implement-sql-intersect-and-minus-operations-in-ms-access

It may be helpful

Comment: That's the one I was referring to in my OP. This doesn't seem to help me, as the option of selecting the table fields in a specific order is missing (I need to intersect the same table but in different field order. A,B and B,A)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with _the syntax doesn't apply to the table_ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For test data in a table named [MirrorTest]

```
pk  A      B    
--  -----  -----
 1  foo    bar  
 2  hello  world
 3  hello  there
 4  world  hello
 5  bar    baz  
 6  bar    foo
```

the query

```sql
    SELECT pk, A, B
    FROM MirrorTest
    WHERE A<=B
UNION ALL
    SELECT pk, B, A
    FROM MirrorTest
    WHERE A>B
```

will return all of the rows such that A<=B, i.e.,

```
pk  A      B    
--  -----  -----
 2  hello  world
 3  hello  there
 5  bar    baz  
 6  bar    foo  
 1  bar    foo  
 4  hello  world
```

Wrap that in an aggregation query to find the candidates for deletion, defined as the larger [pk] value where there are duplicates

```sql
SELECT Max(pk) AS pkToDelete
FROM
    (
        SELECT pk, A, B
        FROM MirrorTest
        WHERE A<=B
    UNION ALL
        SELECT pk, B, A
        FROM MirrorTest
        WHERE A>B
    ) AS u
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

returns

```
pkToDelete
----------
         6
         4
```

so you could just use that in the WHERE clause of a DELETE query

```sql
DELETE FROM MirrorTest
WHERE pk IN
    (
        SELECT Max(pk) AS pkToDelete
        FROM
            (
                SELECT pk, A, B
                FROM MirrorTest
                WHERE A<=B
            UNION ALL
                SELECT pk, B, A
                FROM MirrorTest
                WHERE A>B
            ) AS u
        GROUP BY A, B
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

Comment: Works great, thanks so much! Also love that step-by-step tutorial :)